# Facing issue generating pdf using fpdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

I am getting http500 for the code below,I am not sure what is wrong. I am new to php. I have checked that PDF.php is in the right directory and so does fonts

```
<?php
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','/home/php/File/PDF/fonts/');
require('/home/php/File/PDF.php');
$pdf=new FPDF('P', 'mm', array(100,150));
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('times');
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output("ruchit.pdf", D);
?>
```

Comment: what should i do to post the code in correct formating

Comment: A 500 error is mostly not caused by PHP code, it is a server error code. You should check the web server's error log files for details.

Comment: Turn on error reporting with http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php to see them when the script runs.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure :

- are your path corrects ?

  - do /home/php/File/PDF.php and /home/php/File/PDF/fonts/ really exist ?
  - If I download and install the last version of fpdf, I have : `/.../fpdf16/fpdf.php` and `/.../fpdf16/font/`
  - I have no "File" directory -- but I might not have the same install/version as you
- on your last line of code, you should put quotes arround the `'D'`, to avoid this notice : `Notice: Use of undefined constant D - assumed 'D'`

Just after setting the right pathes for my system, and quoting the constant/string, "it works for me"...

... So, question : do you have any error, in Apache's log for example ?